# How can I pass R variable into sqldf?

Tags: r, sqldf

I have some query like this:

```
sqldf("select TenScore from data where State_P = 'AndhraPradesh'")
```

But I have `"AndhraPradesh"` in a variable `stateValue`. How can I use this variable in a select query in R to get the same result as above.

Please show me the syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
sqldf(sprintf("select TenScore from data where State_P = '%s'", stateValue))
```

Comment: I would not recommend this. See the Example 5 on the sqldf github home page for the method normally used with sqldf.

Answer (score 7):

See [Example 5](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#example-5-insert-variables) on the [sqldf GitHub page](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf).

---

**Example 5. Insert Variables**

Here is an example of inserting evaluated variables into a query using gsubfn quasi-perl-style string interpolation. gsubfn is used by sqldf so it is already loaded. Note that we must use the fn$ prefix to invoke the interpolation functionality:

```
minSL <- 7
limit <- 3
species <- "virginica"
fn$sqldf("select * from iris where \"Sepal.Length\" > $minSL and species = '$species' 
  limit $limit")

##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
## 1          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
## 2          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
## 3          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `fn$sqldf` :

`fn$sqldf("select TenScore from data where State_P = '$stateValue'")`