# Automate column choice in R base order()

Tags: r, automation, sqldf

I am working on an automation project in R. I want to order an input dataset (i.e. dataframe) by row values. **No hardcoded values are allowed, since it's automated code.** Reproducible example below:

```
data("mtcars")
groupBY <- c('cyl','carb')
```

Normally, I would go on and order with this:

```
mtcars_ordered <- mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl,mtcars$carb),]
```

or this:

```
mtcars_ordered <- mtcars[with(mtcars,order(cyl,carb)),]
```

but here I am in the '*automated world*', no hardcoded values. Thus, I am looking for something like this:

```
mtcars_ordered_auto <- mtcars[with(mtcars,order(groupBY)),]
```

`order()` accepts vectors, that is subsets of the data frame, but I can't find a way to do it with R base only.

PS Eventually, I succeeded using fn$sqldf as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547950/how-can-i-pass-r-variable-into-sqldf), by writing:

```
groupBY_str <- paste(groupBY,collapse=',')
mtcars_ordered_sql <- fn$sqldf('select * from mtcars order by $groupBY_str').
```

Nonetheless, I am curious how to solve it with base R.

Comment: Regarding the last line of code in the question with `fn$sqldf` note that you can't have underscores  in names after the $.  They will be regarded as terminating the name, not part of the name. You can either put back quotes around such a name or else use a different name having no special characters.

Comment: I must admit, I edited my question in the browser, without rerunning it in R - I had no way to see this `Error: near "_str": syntax error`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `do.call`

```
mtcars_ordered_auto <- mtcars[do.call(order, mtcars[groupBY]),]
```

-checking with OP's output

```
identical(mtcars_ordered, mtcars_ordered_auto)
#[1] TRUE
```